# How add externals .jar to Ibm Integration Bus 10. java compute

Tags: java, pdf, apache-fop, ibm-integration-bus

I try to create a PDF from an XML using apache fop, i can do it in Netbeans or Eclipse IDE's, but the Java Compute inside the IIB when i try to execute from SOAP UI launch me this java error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/fop/apps/FopFactory

[java error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGCZe.png)

but, i already add the necesaires libraries:

[libraries added without errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8OsB.png)

Here reference is made

[libraries referenced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFhQS.png)

I hope you can help me, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to work, but you simply have to put this jar on the shared-classes.

This folder exist at the execution group (integration server) level, or at the broker (integration node) level. If you plan to reuse it later, I would suggest you to put it at the broker level, otherwise at the execution group level.

Path sample (unix in this case)

```
/var/mqsi/shared-classes (For all your broker on this VM, NOT recommanded)
/var/mqsi/config/"yourBrokerName"/shared-classes (broker level)
/var/mqsi/config/"yourBrokerName"/"yourExecutionGroupName"/shared-classes (execution group level)
```

If you put it at the execution group level, the execution group needs to be restarted. If you put it at the broker level, you should restart the whole broker.

Feel free to contact me if you have other questions, but with the shared-classes keyword, you should be able to find everything you are looking for.